# Http Trigger function throwing error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: azure-functions

Calling out to an external endpoint in the azure function (http trigger).  Get the following error:

System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

It works locally.  Doesn't work when it's deployed to the function app

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a limitation of the endpoint that you are calling, firewall rule or something.

Try calling https://www.google.com from a test function, it will work just fine.

Comment: Also, try to isolate using `curl` from Kudu Console so you run in the sandbox, but without involving anything related to Functions per se.

Comment: this seems to work: 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Was hoping for something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue with a new function app deployment, I was getting the same error message -

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I was using self hosted agent but when I used `Microsoft hosted agent` for deployment it worked. The problem was due to some missing TLS 1.2 settings and Configuring strong cryptography. I had to add below keys in the registry and of course a machine restart afterwards.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```

And it worked as a charm afterwards. [Reference][1]